# Why does Stack Overflow sometimes seem so eager to close "off-topic" that happen to be VERY relevant to the programming community?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, not-constructive

As a computer programmer, I am occasionally looking for answers to questions like "Why the heck would I want to use an IDE over Emacs or Vim?" or "What editor do you like to use, and why?" or "Why doesn't anyone use Common Lisp when it is so powerful?".  These questions understandably create a lot of debate, and are subject to opinion rather than fact, so they are often closed.

The funny thing is, however, that I happen to find a lot of the answers that were given before  the question was closed to be relevant, thoughtful answers--even if they are debatable--and I learn a lot from them!

So, my question is this:  Why aren't considerations such as these (particularly the quality of the answers) taken into consideration, when deciding whether a question is "off-topic" or "subject to debate"?  Particularly when they are HIGHLY relevant to the programming community?

I understand the desire to "run a tight ship", so perhaps a certain mechanism may need to be developed to help accommodate weird questions that violate the letter of the guidelines, but are nonetheless very useful to the community....

Comment: [SO] deals with programming questions, not opinions.

Comment: Don't confuse popularity with suitability to the Q&A format.

Comment: Just because somethings not suitable for stack overflow doesn't mean its not a great article (to be posted elsewhere). SO has a particular purpose and is very good at it. Its purpose isn't to be the be all and end all of programming information

Comment: Note that your feature-request, have a place for recommendation questions, has already been proposed before here on Meta. Over and over again.

Comment: So, are you asking why Stack is not a forum / debate platform?

Comment: This is why [programmers.se] was created.  ***FIRE IN THE HOLE!*** *(dives in bunker)*

Comment: I apologize for adding "feature-request" as a tag; I was required to add it.  I also thought I did due diligence in looking for this specific type or question.  Apparently I was wrong.  :-(  Having said that, if people are requesting it over and over again, it's probably a sign that an important feature (however that feature might be created) is missing somehow.

Comment: To clarify:  I am not asking "Why isn't SO a forum or debate platform?"  The thing is, even controversial questions sometimes deserve answers, and SO seems to be better at it than a forum, where I have to sift through a lot of ick before finding good opinions.  So far at least, SO has been good at bringing out good opinions!  And this makes sense:  there's only so much "debate" you can do with a Q&A format.  Perhaps, rather than be worried that a Q might generate debate, a controversial Q should only be closed if the feared debate has occurred...

Comment: I appreciate the point about "Programmers".  It makes me wonder if there's a "seamless" way to transfer a question from SO to Programmers....

Comment: @AlpheusMadsen flag and specify should be migrated. Note that the point about programmers was somewhat tongue-in-cheek and wrong. They don't allow subjective questions either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of your questions are extensively documented in the help center.

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

And the canonical blog posts:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/
- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/
- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ (linked from FAQ)
- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/ (linked from FAQ)

Comment: Ironically, the most relevant post that answers my question (gorilla-vs-shark), also has a few comments that make the case that I am trying to address:  that there *can* be room for "vs." questions, if handled correctly.  Sadly, I cannot access the "Python vs. Perl" question to see what all the fuss is about, because I have neither the reputation nor the Google cache to do so.  Interestingly enough, the blogposts even describe how to handle subjective questions!  (Namely, by requiring answers to be backed by experience or authority.)

Comment: @AlpheusMadsen I don't think you need to peruse the question to know whether "Python v. Perl" is a good question. Does "Python v. Perl" sound more like "Gorilla v. Shark", or does it sound more like "Are Google+ Circles better UX for sharing among friends than Facebook Groups?"

Comment: given that Jeff Atwood gave it as the quintessential example of why such questions are bad, and that in the comments to the blogpost, at least one person felt that many of the answers to the question were good, I would think that it would be a valuable question to be able to see, even if it's only preserved for historical reasons.  I, for one, am having trouble wrapping my head around this issue; if I can see the question, I could better understand the arguments being made (even if I end up disagreeing with the final decision)....